# Can I detect if I am on a Linux system (and not a generic Unix system) using Ant?

Tags: java, ant

I have the following problem: I have to execute different operation in the case the operating system is Linux and in the case the operating system is MacOs.

So I have create the following Ant script targets:

```
<condition property="unix">
    <os family="unix" />
</condition>

<condition property="mac">
    <os family="mac" />
</condition>

<target name="initUnixPath" if="unix" depends="clean">
    <echo message="initUnixPath: SETTING UNIX PATH" />
    <property name="path">/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/</property>
</target>

<target name="initMacPath" if="mac" depends="clean">
    <echo message="initMacPath: SETTING MAC PATH" />
    <property name="path">${basedir}/../../../Mac/CrystalIce/CrystalIce/CrystalIce/Build/Products/Debug/CrystalIce.app/Contents/Resources/java/</property>
</target>
```

```
    <!-- Copy SharedLib jar files: -->
    <!--<copy todir="${basedir}/../../../../../../../../usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib">-->
    <!--<copy todir="/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib">-->
    <echo message="${path}" />
    <copy todir="${path}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/../../SharedLib" />
    </copy>
            ..................................................
            ..................................................
            COPY OTHER FILES
```

When it go to execute the **init** target this target depends from the **initUnixPath** and **initMacPat** targets

So happens the following thing:

1) If I execute it on a Linux machine it first execute the **initUnixPath** that set the **path** property to the correct value: "/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/", then execute the **initMacPath** and do nothing because the Linux machine is not a MacOs machine. So execute the **init** target and copy the files in the right location: "/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/"

2) If I execute it on a MacOs machine it first execute the **initUnixPath** (because MacOs is a BSD based system so it is a UNIX machine) that set the **path** property to the **WRONG** value "/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/" (because this is the path for Linux system and not for MacOs), then execute the **initMacPath** (because it match) and try to set the CORRECT path for MacOs system ("${basedir}/../../../../../../../../usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib") but it can't do it because the property is just setted and can't be change !!!)

So I have a problem because on a MacOs machine I have that path value is setted to the wrong Linux path ("/usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib/") and not to the right MacOs path ("${basedir}/../../../../../../../../usr/share/XCloud/appl/lib")

The only solution that I have found is to **change the order of the dependency in the init target** from:

```
<target name="init" depends="initUnixPath, initMacPath ">
```

to:

```
<target name="init" depends="initMacPath, initUnixPath ">
```

So it is a Mac set the correct path for the MacOs system, then enter in **initUnixPath** try to set the Linux path but it can't (and work well on Mac)

If it is a Linux system try to exexute **initMacPath** but Linux is not Mac so exit from this target and execute **initUnixPath** where correctly set the Linux path (and work well on Linux)

But this seems to me a very dirty solution !!!

So I am asking if I can detect more precisely if it is a LINUX SYSTEM (and not a generic UNIX System). Can I do it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: You seem to be asking the wrong question here. Are you really planning to *build* your product on both Linux and MacOS? Or just build it once as God & Gosling intended and *deploy* it on multiple platforms?

Answer (score 1):

I always symbolically link binaries I install to `/usr/local/bin`. This way, I don't have to worry whether it was installed in `/Applications` or `/opt` or `/usr/share`, etc. If you don't see the executable in that location (via `<available/>` task), fail the build with instructions on what to do.

```
<property name="bin.link.dir"  value="/usr/local/bin"/>
<available file="${bin.link.dir}/xcloud" <!-- Or whatever the app -->
    property="xcloud.app.available"/>    <!-- Or whatever the app -->
<fail>
   Could not find required app...
   download it from yadda, yadda, yadda...
   Install it by blah, blah, blah...
   Then create a symbolic link to ${link.dir}...
   <condition>
      <not>
         <isset property="xcloud.app.available"/>
      </not>
   </condition>
</fail>
```

You can also use the `uname` command if it is a Unix type system to see if it's Linux or not:

```
<!-- outputs "Darwin" on Mac and "Linux" on Linux -->
<exec executable="uname"
   os="unix"
   outputproperty="os.type"/>

<condition property="linux.os">
    <equals  arg1="${os.type}"  arg2="Linux"/>
</condition>
```